# Would have never VS have/had never

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "I would've never believed that he would win that match" VS "I had/have never believed that he would win that match"

Answer (score 1):

The first one would be used if the person *had* won the match, and you were expressing surprise. "I would never have believed..." is the more usual version.

Your second example is not very idiomatic, but it's just a statement of your opinion.